# reassign struct in C

Tags: c

I'm new to C and experimenting with structs. After I've created a struct, is it possible to reassign it with curly brackets?

```
typedef struct {
    int height;
    int age;
} Person;

int main (void)
{
    Person bill = {100,35};
    bill = {120,34}; // error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
    bill = Person {120,34}; // error: expected expression before ‘Person’

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not directly, but C99 has compound literals for that

```
bill = (Person){120,34};
```

you could even do things more readable by using designated initializers like

```
bill = (Person){ .height = 120, .age = 34, };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works fine with my GCC (OSX GCC version 4.2.1) I don't know much about C variants and the implications of using newer features, Can I ask if this is considered 'standard'?

Comment: @MachineElf There are 4 flavours of the C language: K&R C, C90, C99 and C11. K&R C is pre-standardization, and the two digits of the others stand for the year of release. Compound literals and designated initializers were introduced in C99. The current version of the standard is C11 and it supports these features too. So this should be considered standard indeed - if your compiler can't handle this code it doesn't follow the C standard.