# Don't understand meaning of 1 code line in example code

Tags: c

I've downloaded an example code. It has a code line like

```
 CGPointSPUserResizableViewAnchorPointPair upperRight = { CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width, 0.0), SPUserResizableViewUpperRightAnchorPoint };
```

But when I rewrite it:

```
CGPointSPUserResizableViewAnchorPointPair lowerMiddle;
if (self.isScaled)
{
    lowerMiddle = { CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height), SPUserResizableViewLowerMiddleAnchorPoint };
}
```

And an error appears. So I don't know what the meaning of this code is.

Comment: what example code? what error? what is your expected outcome?

Comment: possible duplicate of [reassign struct in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298070/reassign-struct-in-c)

Comment: -1 for saying "an error appears" and not quoting the exact error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `struct` from your example code is declared like this:

```
typedef struct CGPointSPUserResizableViewAnchorPointPair {
    CGPoint point;
    SPUserResizableViewAnchorPoint anchorPoint;
} CGPointSPUserResizableViewAnchorPointPair;
```

Here's the line of code you quoted, reformatted to be easier to read:

```
CGPointSPUserResizableViewAnchorPointPair upperRight = {
    CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width, 0.0),
    SPUserResizableViewUpperRightAnchorPoint
};
```

Since this line creates the variable, it can use a compound initializer to initialize it.  A compound initializer is a brace-enclosed list containing the initial value of each `struct` member in order<sup>1</sup>.  So the return value of the `CGPointMake` call initializes `upperRight.point`, and the `SPUserResizableViewUpperRightAnchorPoint` variable initializes `upperRight.anchorPoint`.

The assignment to `lowerMiddle` in your rewritten code is not creating the variable, you cannot use a compound initializer.  You need to set the structure members a different way.  One way is to assign to each member in turn:

```
CGPointSPUserResizableViewAnchorPointPair lowerMiddle;
if (self.isScaled)
{
    lowerMiddle.point = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height);
    lowerMiddle.anchorPoint = SPUserResizableViewLowerMiddleAnchorPoint;
}
```

Another way is to use a **compound literal**.  A compound literal is just like a compound initializer in a variable definition, except that you must “cast” it to the proper type:

```
CGPointSPUserResizableViewAnchorPointPair lowerMiddle;
if (self.isScaled)
{
    lowerMiddle = (CGPointSPUserResizableViewAnchorPointPair){
        CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height),
        SPUserResizableViewLowerMiddleAnchorPoint
    };
}
```

---

Footnote 1.  There are other forms for a compound initializer, but this is the simplest and is the form your example uses.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `{ <field>, <field> }` for initializing a struct may only be used in a variable initializer.

**Edit:**

Based on the question that tia linked, this ought to work:

```
lowerMiddle = (CGPointSPUserResizableViewAnchorPointPair) {
    CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height), 
    SPUserResizableViewLowerMiddleAnchorPoint
};
```